# How to increment letters of pointer in assembler?

Tags: c++, assembly, 32-bit, masm

I have procedure in assembler and i want to add to each letter of String strV, which is byte pointer some value, in this case it will be +3. I try to add 3 only for first letter, but proc returns weird sign or nothing, so I asks for help. (Returned pointer will be assigned to char * string in C++).

```
start proc strV: PTR BYTE
    mov eax, [strV]
    ret
start endp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add 3 to each letter of a string ?

The following code is *not* tested, but it should work. Assuming that your string is a NUL-terminated string, of course.

I'm simply checking to see if we're at the end of the string,
if we're not it adds 3 and keeps going.

```
start proc strV: PTR BYTE
    mov eax, strV
next:
    cmp byte ptr [eax], 0
    je done
    add byte ptr [eax], 3
    inc eax
    jmp next
done:
    ret
start endp
```

Comment: `ecx` is redundant here. You can just use `eax` as your pointer register.

Comment: Of course, you're absolutely right, I'll edit the answer. I'm not sure what made me do that.

Comment: I'm writing caesar cipher app where i compare timing for C++ and asm. Your help gave me all what I want : ) thank u